# Add data to table with info from 2 other tables in the same database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables in the same database: **customers**, **items**, and **sales**. I want to add data to the **sales** table with information from the *customers* and *articles* table.

Is that possible? (I think so, I know how to do it from one table to the other but now I need to get the information from 2 different tables) If so, which query should I use? Thank you guys!!!

```
create table clientes (
    dni_cliente INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    apellido VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    telefono INTEGER NOT NULL,
    fecha_alta DATE NOT NULL
);

create table articulos (
    id_articulo SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    units INTEGER NOT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    descripcion VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE ventas (
    n_venta SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    fecha_venta DATE NOT NULL,
    units_vendidas INTEGER NOT NULL,
    dni_cliente1 INTEGER REFERENCES clientes(dni_cliente),
    id_articulo1 SERIAL REFERENCES articulos(id_articulo)
);

insert into articulos (units, nombre, descripcion) values ('49', 'Auriculares', 'Sltr-haris Type I physeal');
insert into articulos (units, nombre, descripcion) values ('11', 'Monitor', 'Newborn small for gestat');
insert into articulos (units, nombre, descripcion) values ('19', 'Mouse', 'Unspecified fracture of upper');

insert into clientes (dni_cliente, nombre, apellido, telefono, fecha_alta) values ('39123876', 'John', 'Doe', '15483283', '2014-07-17 08:09:08');
insert into clientes (dni_cliente, nombre, apellido, telefono, fecha_alta) values ('40363302', 'Lucas', 'Mises', '15474656', '2014-10-11 10:27:51');
insert into clientes (dni_cliente, nombre, apellido, telefono, fecha_alta) values ('43024546', 'Gustavo', 'Demarco', '15422673', '2012-09-18 08:31:25');
```

Comment: Of course it's possible. You should use subqueries to do that. Please, be more specific to help you on creating the queries and subqueries you need...

Comment: The answer is "yes" to your question.  If you only explained the logic you want to implement (i.e. what data to insert), then you would have a question that could be answered.

Answer (score 0):

it is definitely possible but you should use joins, i dont know what information do you want to add from the tow tables so i ll just give you a random example of the query:

```
INSERT into tbl_employee_accounts(username, type)
SELECT tbl_users.username, tbl_user_types.type 
FROM tbl_users inner join tbl_user_types ON tbl_users.id = tbl_user_types.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible and is even the norm. What you describe is inserting into a resolution table (ventas) with intersecting data for the M:M relationship between the others (clientes:articulos).  If you have the foreign key values (dni_cliente1 and id_articulo1) available then it is just a simple values insert.

```
insert into ventas(fecha_venta,units_vendidas,dni_cliente1,id_articulo1) 
     values (current_date, 2, 39123876,1) ;
```

If as your question implies, you do not have the FK values then you must have some other column value(s) available (unique if at all possible) then you can select the necessary values form their source tables. For example suppose you have the item and customer names, then

```
insert into ventas(fecha_venta,units_vendidas,dni_cliente1,id_articulo1)
     select current_date, 4
          , (select dni_cliente from clientes where (nombre,apellido) = ('Lucas', 'Mises') )
          , (select id_articulo from articulos where nombre = 'Monitor');
```

There are many other possibilities, but most will follow the same general pattern. See [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a74ec2c67e42231f8ef51e633091b89a).  
BTW there is an error in the table description. The table ventas has the following column "id_articulo1 SERIAL REFERENCES articulos(id_articulo)" This is basically a self contradicting statement. Defining it as SERIAL implies the system can automatically generate a value while REFERENCES requires it already exists in another table. The definition should be "id_articulo1 integer REFERENCES articulos(id_articulo)".